# Why will this mp4 file (generated by ffmpeg) play on safari but NOT firefox?

Tags: firefox, video, ffmpeg, safari

I have an mp4 file (that's blank space, I use it to test subtitles) It's currently sitting at http://projectgrin.org/SubtitlePlayer/video/output.mp4. I generated it with ffmpeg.

My notes are incomplete and it was a while ago, but these are the commands that could have generated it:

```
joereddington@windstone:~$ history | grep ffmpeg
   3925  ffmpeg -t 2000 -s 320x240 -f E -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 5 -i /dev/zero short.mpeg
 3927  ffmpeg -t 2000 -s 320x240 -f mp4 -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 5 -i /dev/zero short.mpeg
 3928  ffmpeg -t 2000 -s 320x240 -f rawdata -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 5 -i /dev/zero short.mpeg
 3929  ffmpeg -t 2000 -s 320x240 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 5 -i /dev/zero short.mpeg
 3930  ffmpeg -t 2000 -s 320x240 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 10 -i /dev/zero short.mpeg
 3932  ffmpeg -t 2000 -s 320x240 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 24 -i /dev/zero short.mpeg
 3941  ffmpeg -i /dev/zero -acodec libfaac -b:a 128k -vcodec mpeg4 -b:v 1200k -flags +aic+mv4 output.mp4
 3942  ffmpeg -i video/short.mpeg -qscale 0 output.mp4
 3943  ffmpeg -i video/short.mpeg  output.mp4
```

Oddly, the file plays fine when I visit the link with Safari, but NOT with Firefox (40.0.3).   Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am unaware of any browser that natively supports MPEG-4 Part 2 video. I'm guessing Safari uses QuickTime to play your video. Use H.264 video instead.

## black video

[image: color filter output]

If you want a "blank" video that should be playable with any modern, sane browser you can use the [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc) filter:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=d=60 -c:v libx264 -profile:v main \
-movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

## testsrc & sine

[image: testsrc]

If you want something a little more interesting, with a timestamp and audio tone use [testsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color_002c-haldclutsrc_002c-nullsrc_002c-rgbtestsrc_002c-smptebars_002c-smptehdbars_002c-testsrc) and [sine](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#sine):

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i testsrc=d=60,format=yuv420p -f lavfi -i sine \
-c:v libx264 -profile:v main -c:a aac -strict experimental -movflags +faststart \
-shortest output.mp4
```